# Learning Android NDK

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I am an android app developer and developed apps using android sdk but now i want to learn working with NDK, JNI , and working with the libraries.I have successfully executed the tutorial by Markana [Learning JNI](http://marakana.com/forums/android/examples/49.html)

I want to know other links of the tutorial related to NDK or JNI or anything that can make me comfortable to use NDK in advanced level.

Thanks

Comment: Asking for links to tutorials is not considered a good fit to this site's Q&A format. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/139008/are-questions-asking-for-tutorials-allowed

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See this tutorial: http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/ndk-tutorial/

ebook: http://www.ebook3000.com/Android-NDK-Beginner-s-Guide_155154.html

Comment: thanks. But isn't there few other blogs that tells more practically about the NDK.The e-book is not free too.